# Reproofing a coat

Tags: waterproof-clothing

I am reproofing an Isotex™ coat which somebody had previously laundered and destroyed its waterproof properties. I don't know what grade the fabric is, but it is probably not the lowest as the coat has two sets of zippers protected by an overlapping storm flap.

The manufacturer's website [care instructions](https://www.regatta.com/garment-care/) don't give much guidance.

> **Do I really need to reproof my garment?**
> Reproofing your garment on a regular basis enhances its technical performance. Every time the jacket is washed as directed on the care label, it should also be re-proofed. Use either Regatta Wash-in Reproofer or Regatta spray-on Reproofer.

I decided to use the wash-in treatment, not a spray. The instruction on the bottle says

> Shake well and pour 75ml into conditioner compartment of the washing machine. Wash garment following manufacturer's guidelines.

and some more about tumble-drying and ironing, which I didn't do. The coat was spun and is hanging to dry; I'll turn it inside out when the outside is dry.

---

I plan to give the coat a second proofing treatment, but

- hand treat in a bucket
- start with dry fabric
- use just enough water plus reproofer to saturate the coat
- drip dry
- turn inside out to finish drying

Is this wrong, or am I overdoing this and need only to repeat the washing machine conditioner cycle? Or was the first step already enough?

I would appreciate any advice readers might have on the best course of action. I have read some of the  previous questions:
[I need to wash my waterproof coat without ruining the waterproofing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17200/i-need-to-wash-my-waterproof-coat-without-ruining-the-waterproofing)
[My Rab jacket is no longer water proof/resistant after wash](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27986/my-rab-jacket-is-no-longer-water-proof-resistant-after-wash)

Comment: The waterproof a jacket there are two steps. 1) Cleaning step 2) Waterproofing step. For both steps just follow the directions on the bottles. They are there for a reason. Meaning don't skip the tumble drying. It helps set the DWR.

Comment: @noah thank you, I don't have a tumble dryer. The garment advises a light tumble or light iron. I have made a second treatment in a bucket by hand. I will iron it lightly, then repeat to use up the bottle, again followed by light ironing (when dry).

Comment: I wouldn't iron. It won't be as even and if done at too high of a heat can easily ruin the garment. It's worth the $5 to go to a laundromat for an hour and tumble dry it.

Comment: @noah and I won't be able to reach into all the crevices with an iron. The waterproofing will only be as good as the weakest spot.

Comment: I also don't have a tumble dryer, but could make use of one for a one-off. Or I'd choose a different product. It might be worth asking the manufacturer if there's an alternative approach. I wonder how hot is needed, and whether that temperature could be obtained by hanging it up in a very small room with a fan heater on max (probably directed away from the coat, but maybe finishing off with a hairdryer directly at it)

Comment: @ChrisH I chose the wash additive because I thought it would result in a more thorough and even treatment than a spray. Wash 1: by machine with rinse additive, hang coat to dry. Wash 2: a soak and rinse by hand with the additive and 2L water in a bucket, for better concentration, hang coat to dry. One dose remaining. I can tell by flicking water at the coat that it still isn't remotely waterproof.

Comment: @WeatherVane I also like wash-in more (plus I never get a still enough day to spray outside and I'd rather not have the fumes in the house).  I was thinking more of [Nikwax TX Direct](https://www.nikwax.com/en-gb/products/tx-direct-wash-in/#) which is a wash-in treatment that specifically doesn't need cooking afterwards. I may do my old tent with it soon (though I don't think I've got enough left for that)

Comment: @ChrisH thanks. Sadly I'll then have spent the £25 in total which the local dry cleaner quoted for a clean and reproofing :(